# Android: Expanding and collapsing toolbars without AppCompat library

Tags: android

In my application I'm using the theme @android:style/Theme.Material because I like the dark material design.

I would like to implement an expanding and collapsing toolbars like the one in "Build a Material Design App with the Android Design Support Library" from Codelab.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VxgE.gif

The problem is that it's require the widget CoordinatorLayout that seems to be incompatible with this theme.

Is there any solution that doesn't require to change the theme ?
If not, is it possible to have a dark material look with AppCompat ?

Comment: Is there a specific error you're getting? I don't think there's a dependency on `AppCompat` for the `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.

Comment: Ah ok, so the problem is not in the `CoordinatorLayout`, but in the design library that you're using. Unless you want to remove your library dependencies, might be worth setting your parent theme to extend `Theme.AppCompat` and adding `appcompat` to your build file.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced @android:style/Theme.Material by Theme.AppCompat and add appcompat-v7 in my dependencies.
Also I replaced every extends Activity by extends AppCompatActivity in my java code.

Now my application can run without this error.